# Getting visual feedback of workspace switch in KDE

Tags: kde, workspaces

I've just installed KDE on Linux Mint. One feature I miss from cinnamon regarding workspaces is indication on what workspace I've just switched.

I'm completely new to KDE but so far I can't find anything like this in default system.

Comment: I found this: http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/Conky+Workspace+Indicator?content=165327 but it is not any official software, so be cautious :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KDE uses the term **workspace** to refer to the whole kit and kaboodle, not individual parts.  (Virtual) **desktops** is used to refer to screen pages, and **activities** to groups of desktops.

If you look in *System Settings -> Workspace Behavior -> Virtual Desktops* you'll see a *Switching* tab where you can set animations.  You can also tick *Desktop Switch On-Screen Display* which will flash a pager briefly when you move.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, however is there a way to pin toolbar to the workspace? i.e. every workspace having it's own toolbar?

Comment: You mean *every desktop* ;)  AFAIK, no, panels are part of the (global) workspace.  You can have more than one and hide them though.  BTW WRT switching I find Ctrl-F8 useful; it zooms a view of all desks in and out.

Comment: Thanks, ctrl-f8 is definitely useful! I guess one panel is for the best as well.

Answer (score 0):

KDE4:
Some additional infos, some of which I couldn't find anywhere online:

Making sure:

1. the OSD message telling you on which workspace you are on is always on the same display and does NOT jump around
2. the size of the OSD message is not unnecessarily large

How-to (for KDE4):

1. Reading the KDE4 config files helped me here. The OSD message always appears on the "active display", therefore you just have to make sure the display on which your mouse cursor is on is in fact the active display (don't worry, it does not mean that any window loses focus when you hold the cursor on the other display while using it or anything).
   Go to "System Settings" → "Window Behaviour" → "Window Behaviour": "Active screen follows mouse" - activate this option.
   Now when switching the workspace the OSD message telling you which workspace you are on will always appear on the same display your mouse cursor is on.
2. The easiest way to reduce the overly large OSD message box around the text that tells you which workspace you are on is to let a KDE4 plasmoid do the work for you. The plasmoid is already pre-installed and is called "Pager" aka "Workspace Switcher". It not only displays the windows on each workspace in small icons but also lets you configure almost all options regarding workspace switching. Just hold the mouse cursor on the widget and select the options button that pops up on the side.
   Just click through the options, you'll find everything you need here.
   The important thing is: when you activate the "workspace OSD message" with this tool, the message box (frame) is only as big as the text.