# Preview of workspace OSD when switching as in gnome-unity (for KDE)

Tags: kde, workspaces, plasma

I know [from here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138957/getting-visual-feedback-of-workspace-switch-in-kde) one can activate a visible feedback when switching from one workspace to another in KDE/PLASMA.

This only shows which desktop is being used by means of arrow and numbers. Is there a way to obtain a view of the workspaces in there as in gnome-unity / Ubuntu ?

EDIT: the picture shows what happens when I switch from one workspace to the next. The blue square is the arrival workspace, and the arrow signals the workspace I am moving from. Is it possible to have previews in here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Desktop Grid effect should work for you, if I understand your question correctly. It is located here: System Settings - Desktop Effects - All Effects tab.

Comment: The desktop grid effect is on, but calling it with its shortcut doesn't do anything. Also, I am not sure is related. I am posting pictures in the question to clarify.

Comment: May be you have conflicting key bindings, you can try to change it.

Comment: On edit: it is not possible, closest thing you can get is the Desktop Grid effect. You can open a feature request at the bugs.kde.org though.